# Lua : create the simplest possible program that is still considered "correct."

Tags: lua

i want to know that how can we create simplest possible program that is still considered "correct" as programmability.
Example :
In python a blank .py file is a simple possible program that is programmability correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same in Lua: the empty program is correct.

Comment: That's really weird - it works for me too, as does `;;` even though http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html explicitly states that there are no empty statements... actually scratch that, I was looking at the old version: the new one explicitly states that there are empty statements: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.1

Comment: The empty statement is invalid (in 5.1). But an empty file has NO statements (not even an empty one).